# How do the bitwise operations work?

Tags: javascript, python, bitwise-operators

I have come across strange operators such as `&`, `|`, `^` etc. How exactly do these operators work?

```
>>> 10 | 7
15
>>> 10 ^ 7
13
>>> 10 & 7
2
>>>
```

The pattern does seem quite odd, and most of the sources out there do not give answers that are easy to comprehend.

Comment: They operate on the bits - the 0s and 1s. It won't make much sense if you're looking at the numbers' decimal representations.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, I am aware, which is why I answered it further down. However, I, like many others, was confused by them when I first started coding, and I hope this will serve as something like a reference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a blog.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Self-answered questions are completely fine on SO. However, I find it hard to believe this one doesn't have a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @user1823: either tag this with JavaScript, or with Python. Not with both.

Comment: "How exactly do these operators work?" I'm excited and can't wait to see some circuit diagrams of how to implement AND, OR and eXclusiveOR gates for a 32-bit binary number!

Comment: @user1823: If you're going to post something like this on SO, it's generally a good idea to stick around a bit to respond to comments / questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **[BITWISE AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND)**

Each item in row `1` is **multiplied** by the corresponding value in row `2`:

```
a = 5     # In binary: 0101
b = 3     # In binary: 0011
c = a & b # In binary: 0001

print c   # In decimal: 1
```

## **[BITWISE OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR)**

If **any** item in either row is `1`, the corresponding result is `1`:

```
a = 5     # In binary: 0101
b = 3     # In binary: 0011
c = a | b # In binary: 0111

print c   # In decimal: 7
```

## **[BITWISE XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR)**

If the items in each column are different from each other, the result is `1`:

```
a = 5     # In binary: 0101
b = 3     # In binary: 0011
c = a ^ b # In binary: 0110

print c   # In decimal: 6
```

Comment: `print someVariable` isn't valid JS.

Comment: @Cerbrus this looks like _Python_, also the XOR is currently using the wrong operator

Comment: @user1823 it might also be good to explain why things like this happen `0x80000000 | 64; // -2147483584`

Answer (score -2):

This might be helpful to you

[Bitwise operators guide in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

You can use chrome javascript console to test all these operators also.

In javascript try like this

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 6;



console.log((a & b)); //AND

console.log((a | b)); //OR

console.log((a ^ b)); //XOR

console.log((~a)); //NOT

console.log((a << b)); //Left Shift

console.log((a >> b)); //Sign propagating right shift

console.log((a >>> b)); //Zero fill right shift
```